# Using reflection for generically typed delegate and interfaces

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

I have a bunch of classes that each have a property called Sequence. This property is implemented from an interface called ISequenced. For this example lets call one of these classes A.
When I have a List(of A), I want to be able to sort them using the standard List.Sort(addressof delegate) where the delegate is a standard function that takes in two ISequenced objects and compares their sequence numbers and returns a boolean flag, rather than declaring a function for each individual class that implements ISequenced.

E.g.

```
Dim li as List(of A) = GetValues()

li.Sort(addressof SortBySeq)

...

Public Function SortBySeq(ByVal ob1 as ISequenced, ByVal ob2 as ISequenced) as Boolean
   return ob1.Sequence.CompareTo(ob2.Sequence)
End If
```

EDIT: Using the above gives me the following error:

> "Overload resolution failed because no
>   accessible 'Sort' can be called with
>   these arguments:
>       'Public Sub Sort(comparison As System.Comparison(Of A))': Option
>   Strict On does not allow narrowing in
>   implicit type conversions between
>   method 'Public Function SortBySeq(ob1
>   As ISequenced, ob2 As ISequenced) As
>   Integer' and delegate 'Delegate
>   Function Comparison(Of A)(x As A, y As
>   A) As Integer'.
>       'Public Sub Sort(comparer As System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of
>   A))': 'AddressOf' expression cannot be
>   converted to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of
>   A)' because
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of
>   A)' is not a delegate type."

How would I declare the function in order to do this (if it is even possible in VB.NET?

Thanks,
Dane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't need to implement IComparer in the end as I was only comparing decimals. Turns out that .NET 3.5 added at least some covariance abilities with delegates so I've upgraded to that and the example I gave above seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Implement an IComparer. Everything you need is [here](http://devintelligence.com/2007/01/sorting-system-collections-generic-list-t/).

Edit:
Oh, I see what the rub is. All the classes that have the Sequence property must implement an interface to be comparable. E.g. use IHaveSequence and do an IComparer< IHaveSequence>.  IHaveSequence's definition should be obvious.

Comment: IComparer will allow me to compare two objects of the same class but I don't want to have to implement a function for each class that uses the interface ISequenced. I have expanded my question with a code sample which might give you a better idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I guess it really should be IHasSequence.